# Submitting form with multiple conditions in Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have an angular form that checks the user info and submit the database. The conditions are below:

- The user should be older than 64,
- User transportation value should be 'yes'
- use should live certain zip codes.
  ,

The code that I came up with is just checking age and transportation. Whenever I type a zip code, for instance, 12345, it success which it shouldn't be. What would be the better design for this idea? Any help will be appreciated.

```
  submit() {
if (
  this.getAge(this.member.dateOfBirth) >= 65 &&
  this.member.transportation === 'yes' ||
  this.member.zip === '21202' ||
  this.member.zip === '21205' ||
  this.member.zip === '21213' ||
  this.member.zip === '21219' ||
  this.member.zip === '21237' ||
  this.member.zip === '21222' ||
  this.member.zip === '21224' ||
  this.member.zip === '21217' ||
  this.member.zip === '21231'
) {
  alert('success for checking conditions');
} else {
  alert('Not success!');
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using validators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly if `this.getAge(this.member.dateOfBirth) >= 65 && this.member.transportation === 'yes'` evaluate to true, everything else is ignored.

What you didnt tested, is that if you provide wrong age and non transportation but valid zipcode eg `21202` whole expresion will evaluate to true as well :)

try

```
     this.getAge(this.member.dateOfBirth) >= 65 && this.member.transportation === 'yes' &&
(
      this.member.zip === '21202' ||
      this.member.zip === '21205' ||
      this.member.zip === '21213' ||
      this.member.zip === '21219' ||
      this.member.zip === '21237' ||
      this.member.zip === '21222' ||
      this.member.zip === '21224' ||
      this.member.zip === '21217' ||
      this.member.zip === '21231')
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be something like this:

```
if (this.getAge(this.member.dateOfBirth) >= 65 &&
    this.member.transportation === 'yes' &&
    ['21202', '21205', '21213', '21219', '21237',
     '21222', '21224', '21217', '21231'].indexOf(this.member.zip) >= 0) {
  alert('success for checking conditions');
} else {
  alert('Not success!');
  return false;
}
```